# Changing value of cell based on Category in a budget

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a simple budget in excel and I want a macro to see which category I have made changes to and then add the change to an overall overview of the money used in that category.

That is I have at the top of my sheet a cell for the category "Food".
Further down the sheet I put in the following:
Date;    Category;    Amount of money used.

My code has been used by a button until now.The button checks if the cell 5 places to the left has the value "Dagligvare" and then changes a value somewhere else in the sheet.
My problem is that sometimes the Button recognize the word and sometimes it doesn't. So my question is: Can anybody see why it only works sometimes even though I don't change anything?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim celltxt As String
    celltxt = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Text
    If InStr(1, celltxt, "Dagligvare") Then
         Range("C9") = 3
    Else
         MsgBox ("Nope")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are defining the cell by Offset; this means it is calculated relative to the active cell. Are you sure you're always on the correct cell before you press the button?

Comment: do you know that `InStr()` by default is case-sensitive? therefore `Dagligvare` and `dagligvare` will give different results

Comment: consider the `Worksheet_Change` event which will fire every time you make a change in the worksheet, but can also be limited to firing when only certain cells change. Or consider a simple formula `IF` statement and scrap vba altogether (saying that without knowing the full scope of your efforts).

Comment: Thank you! All of you! It was what Grade 'Eh' Bacon said that was my main problem, I thought the cell I currently was in was the one with the button. But all the other answers worked for other problems.

Scott: I could have used one if I knew how. I am used to programming in Python and find VBA easier to learn than all the commands in excel. How would you make one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a further msgbox to ensure user has the correct activecell

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim celltxt As String

    if (activecell.column = 10) then '<<change 10 to appropriate column

      celltxt = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Text
      If InStr(1, celltxt, "Dagligvare") Then
           Range("C9") = 3
      Else
           MsgBox ("Nope")
      End If
    else
           MsgBox ("Oi! You need to have a cell in column 10 selected")
    end

End Sub
```